# How to dismiss Bluetooth pairing request dialog programmatically in Android device which have no touch screen & no key board attached?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Requirement:

Bluetooth pairing between wince device with Android device(Tab, Android USB Dongle)

Implementation:

Here is my Android code snippet to dismiss Bluetooth pairing request dialog with out any user intervention.

//Code snippet..

public class BluetoothPairingRequest extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST")) {

        try {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            int pin=intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY", 0);
            //the pin in case you need to accept for an specific pin                   

            byte[] pinBytes;
            pinBytes = ("" + pin).getBytes("UTF-8");
            device.setPin(pinBytes);
            //setPairing confirmation if neeeded
            device.setPairingConfirmation(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Problem statement:

The above code snippet is working fine but some times during testing I have seen that:

1. The Bluetooth pairing request dialog is not dismissed with this code and pairing not successful.
2. Also some times when the Bluetooth pairing request dialog is appeared as notification in android status bar then the code is not working and pairing not successful.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?